# CAB in ListView with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-listview, actionbarsherlock, contextual-action-bar

I have custom ListView and I am using ActionBarSherlock. I decided to use contextual action bar for that ListView, but i had some troubles. Most of my problems was resolved by answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10682119/1121362, but one remained - is there any way to achieve that functionality with `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you update your question describing what did you achive and what still dosn't work? Where is the problem?