# .onCreateActionMode in multichoice modal not inflating menu

Tags: android

I'm attempting to get contextual action bar working in a fragment to get multiple deletes. I'm placing this within the check API 11 and after. I'm using Sherlock Fragment for backward compatibility. I have set the choice mode and listener for multiple selections.

The Problem is when `onCreateActionMode` is called it`s failing to inflate the menu; I already have an inflated menu in this fragment. The CAB code is more or less the same as in example [Multiple selection in custom ListView with CAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598348/multiple-selection-in-custom-listview-with-cab) and it is working perfectly well when I try it on its own separately. I am not sure what is going wrong here -is it a conflict with sherlockfragment or is it because of the existing menu or is there some minor correction that I'm missing.

I also have the problem that now that I have set a long click listener my onclick listener is never triggered but I think I have found a post addressing that problem.

I'm pasting snippets below

```
        @Override
        public View onCreateView...
        {
            View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_event_empty_list, parent,false);


            ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

            listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
                listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener(){

            ........        

                    @Override
                    public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode,
                            android.view.Menu menu) {
                            android.view.MenuInflater inflater=mode.getMenuInflater();

                        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_event_context_menu,menu);
    ......
```

Answer (score 1):

sorry guys this got resolved - I was returning false from onCreateActionMode, which seemed to be causing the problem.

Comment: accept your own answer then, and close this question.