# Creating multiple selection list Android

Tags: java, android, listview, spinner, checkedtextview

I would like to add a form of input in my app where a list of options appear and multiple choices can be selected. I would use a spinner, but that only allows one option to be selected. I would then need for the options selected to be sensed for me to perform further operations with this. I think I would need something involving a checkedlistview but I am not sure. What would be the best way to go about doing this? I hope my situation is understood.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598348/multiple-selection-in-custom-listview-with-cab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use checkedlistview it Help you

**ListMain.Java**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
public class ListMain extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.companionsearch_listView1);
        String[] list={"one","two","three"};
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListMain.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,list);
        mylist.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        mylist.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottombarbuttonlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/companionsearch_listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Output:

[image]